# Error al importar una libreria : "Message: 8593 is not in required range"

Tags: python, python-import

```
import sys
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\bs4")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\DLLs")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Doc")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\include")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Lib")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\libs")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\tcl")
sys.path.append("C:\Users\BOIG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Tools")

import bs4
```

y me aparece esto:

```
Message: 8593 is not in required range
```

anteriormente si se cargaba la libreria perfectamente

Comment: ¿Es ese todo el código que hay en tu programa? Es decir... ¿sólo con `import bs4` ya te salta ese error? Y ¿por qué añades todas aseas rutas a `sys.path`?

Comment: Estoy programando un pluggin para un software llamado rhinoceros y necesito cargar las librerias a el programa para poderlas utilizar, anteriormente funcionaban bien, asi tal cual pero ahora me sale un error. No se si sea de python o de el programa.